# change JSON elasticsearch query to python

Tags: python, json, django, elasticsearch

I have been using basic queries in python for elasticsearch like this:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
es = Elasticsearch()

def someView(request):
    s = Search().query("regexp", title_en="someword.*")
    response = s.execute()
```

I would like to combine a query to check if someword exists in either of the fields "title_en" or "text_en" 
Any idea how to accomplish this?

In [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-bool-query.html) link I saw an example of a bool query using JSON, but I don´t understand how something similar could be done with python code.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term" : { "tag" : "tech" }
      },
      "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
          "age" : { "gte" : 10, "lte" : 20 }
        }
      },
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "tag" : "wow" } },
        { "term" : { "tag" : "elasticsearch" } }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the way to use or in query :

```
q = Q("regexp", text_en='someword.*') | Q("regexp", title_en='someword.*')

c = Search().query(q)
response = c.execute()
```